# Some confusion with width in css

Tags: css, width

```
<p style="width: 20%; border: 1px solid black">ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd1</p>
```

In above code, ddd.. overshoots the border, even if I have given it a width of 20%. Shouldn't it stop at 20% width of its content area? Can you explain what actually does width: 20% mean in this code?

Comment: It'll be set to 20% the width of its parent element in the DOM. If you don't want it to overshoot, specify `overflow:scroll;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

[This](https://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/) is an amazing article, which helped me to understand a lot of things regarding overflow property. Anyways, even though I wasn't clear myself, I had following confusions in my mind:

**Q. If the width of the div has been set to 20%, shouldn't the content inside respect that and stay inside that width, rather that overshooting the width?**

A. No. By setting Width and height we just reserve the space for the div in the normal flow of the document. In other words, width and height are the dimensions of content area of the width.However, whether the actual content will respect specified width/height will by determined by `overflow` property. By default we have `overflow: visible` set on all element. This means that that content will overshoot the boundry and be visible outside the boundery.The important thing to remember here is that even though the content is visible outside of the box, that content does not affect the flow of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Use word wrap.

```css
p {
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<p style="width: 20%; border: 1px solid black">ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd1</p>
```

Comment: I am not looking for a solution to the problem, but for an explanation why is it overshooting and what does width:20% mean. Can you explain, please?

Comment: width 20% means it will use 20% of the width of the parent (in this case the body). Dealing with long words that don't fit in the defined container is a common problem. For more details see here: https://justmarkup.com/log/2015/07/dealing-with-long-words-in-css/

Answer (score -1):

You can restrict the content from overflowing by adding

```
p{
overflow: hidden;
}
```

or

```
p{
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Please Up vote if help full